# Toggle set of images with btn-group

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I don't want to display all of the images at once, because it just jumbles the page design. I would like to click a button in a bootstrap btn-group and the appropriate image shows up. Not a javascript/ jquery guy so I need a little help.

```
  <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Front</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Back</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Left</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Right</button>
  </div>

  <div class="front-product-img">
    <% front = @product['colors'][0]['images'].find{|img| img['label'] == 'Front'} %>
    <%= image_tag front['url'], class: 'img-responsive' if front.present? %>
  </div>

  <div class="back-product-img">
    <% back = @product['colors'][0]['images'].find{|img| img['label'] == 'Back'} %>
    <%= image_tag back['url'], class: 'img-responsive' if back.present? %>
  </div>

  <div class="left-product-img">
    <% left = @product['colors'][0]['images'].find{|img| img['label'] == 'Left'} %>
    <%= image_tag left['url'], class: 'img-responsive' if left.present? %>
  </div>

  <div class="right-product-img">
    <% right = @product['colors'][0]['images'].find{|img| img['label'] == 'Right'} %>
    <%= image_tag right['url'], class: 'img-responsive' if right.present? %>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".btn-group[role='group'] button[type=button]").click(function() {
$("."+$(this).text().toLowerCase()+"-product-img").toggle();
});
```

use the above piece of code for your requirement..

Comment: Its not quite right, close. I can't even describe what its doing because it does something different every time I reload. First its showing all the images on page load. when i click the front btn it show back and then it doesnt show that img anymore. Wish I could describe it better but im confused at what it is doing.